# Complex Solutions to Polynomials

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to use topology to prove that:

$z^{n} + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + ... + a_{1}z + a_{0} = 0$

has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if, for each positive real number $c$, the equation

$z^n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{c}z^{n-1} + ... + \frac{a_1}{c^{n-1}}z + \frac{a_0}{c^n} = 0 $

has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$

But I'm having trouble getting going on it.

From experimentation I think there must be some function that takes c, and the roots of the second question, and returns the roots of the first equation (or vice versa) but I'm not seeing why that would be the case.

Hints?

Comment: A polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ always has a root. Your statement is trivially true. For the connection between the roots though, try multiplying the second equation by $c^n$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I think this question is being asked as a part of the topological proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra, so using that fact would be circular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that 
$$(cz)^{n} + a_{n-1}(cz)^{n-1} + ... + a_{1}(cz) + a_{0} = c^nz^{n} + a_{n-1}c^{n-1}z^{n-1} + ... + a_{1}cz + a_{0}$$

Now divide through by $c^n$ to obtain $z^n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{c}z^{n-1} + ... + \frac{a_1}{c^{n-1}}z + \frac{a_0}{c^n}$.

Writing $p_1, p_2$ for the two polynomials of interest, we have $p_1(cz)/c^n = p_2(z)$.  So the existence of a root $w$ for $p_1$ implies the existence of a root $w/c$ for $p_2$.

(Thinking of each of these polynomials as functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, they only differ by some pre- and post-composition with some scaling.  Since the scaling preserves $0$, it doesn't affect the existence of roots.)

Comment: We Got it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $z_0$ is a soloution of the second equation if and only if of $cz_0$ is a soloution of the first equation.